# Create id based on two conditions

Tags: r

I need to create group **id** based on groupid and school. The same **Groupid** is found in different **schools** so I need to create **id** to solve this problem without remove **Groupid**.

```r
data <- data.frame(Groupid = c(1,1,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,8,8,1,1, 4,4,4), 
                   School=c("a", "a", "a","a", "a", "b" ,"b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c" ))
data
```

- I tried it using the following code:

```r
data1 <- data %>% group_by(School) %>% transform(id = as.numeric(factor(Groupid))) %>% relocate(id, .before =  Groupid)
data1
```

output

```
 id Groupid School
  1       1      a
  1       1      a
  3       3      a
  3       3      a
  3       3      a
  4       4      b
  4       4      b
  4       4      b
  4       4      b
  2       2      c
  2       2      c
  2       2      c
  5       8      c
  5       8      c
  1       1      c
  1       1      c
  4       4      c
  4       4      c
  4       4      c
```

Desired output

```
    id Groupid School
  1       1      a
  1       1      a
  2       3      a
  2       3      a
  2       3      a
  3       4      b
  3       4      b
  3       4      b
  3       4      b
  4       2      c
  4       2      c
  4       2      c
  5       8      c
  5       8      c
  6       1      c
  6       1      c
  7       4      c
  7       4      c
  7       4      c
```

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base R option -

```
tmp <- do.call(paste, data)
#If there are more columns. 
#tmp <- do.call(paste, data[c('Groupid', 'School')])
data$id <- match(tmp, unique(tmp))
data

#   Groupid School id
#1        1      a  1
#2        1      a  1
#3        3      a  2
#4        3      a  2
#5        3      a  2
#6        4      b  3
#7        4      b  3
#8        4      b  3
#9        4      b  3
#10       2      c  4
#11       2      c  4
#12       2      c  4
#13       8      c  5
#14       8      c  5
#15       1      c  6
#16       1      c  6
#17       4      c  7
#18       4      c  7
#19       4      c  7
```

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` option

```
data %>%
  group_by(School, Groupid) %>%
  mutate(id = group_indices())
```

Answer (score 0):

In the newer versions of `dplyr`, use `cur_group_id`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
    group_by(School, Groupid) %>% 
    mutate(id = cur_group_id()) %>% 
    ungroup
```

---

Or use `factor`

```
library(tidyr)
data %>%
    unite(id, Groupid, School, remove = FALSE) %>%
    mutate(id = as.integer(factor(id, levels = unique(id))))
```

-output

```
id Groupid School
1   1       1      a
2   1       1      a
3   2       3      a
4   2       3      a
5   2       3      a
6   3       4      b
7   3       4      b
8   3       4      b
9   3       4      b
10  4       2      c
11  4       2      c
12  4       2      c
13  5       8      c
14  5       8      c
15  6       1      c
16  6       1      c
17  7       4      c
18  7       4      c
19  7       4      c
```